# C program behaving differently depending on how it is started

Tags: c, batch-file, command, exe, command-prompt

I have made a real basic spaghetti program to read in a file and output which lines have certain bits set on each line. The output should display which lines contain a bit in position x, a bit in position y etc. The coding is not perfect I'm sure but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

char job[10], filename[10], filename2[10], c;
int pid, seq, end, num = 0, count = 0;
char *p;

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char c; // To store a character read from file

    printf("Enter the file number (6 digits): ");
    scanf("%d", & pid);
    sprintf(filename, "I:\\%d.txt", pid);
    sprintf(filename2, "I:\\%d.RUN", pid);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen(filename2, "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Could not open file %d", pid);
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
        if (c == '\n')
            count = count + 1;

    // Close the file
    fclose(fp);

    int loop, array2[100];
    char compare, str[1000], real[31];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 6; ii++) {
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fp = fopen(filename2, "r");

            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Could not open file %d", pid);
                _getch();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\n\nHopper %d:\n", ii + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);
            strncpy(real, str, 29);
            compare = real[14 + ii];
            if (strcmp( & compare, "1") == 0) {
                printf("%06d  ", i + 1);
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    printf("\n\nYou're welcome!\nPress any key to continue");

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

In summary the program asks the user to type a file number. the file is opened and the number of lines is counted. Then each line is read via fgets and if a '1' is set in a certain position this will print the line number.

My issue is that I'm using this program on a Windows machine (program compiled using MinGW compiler) and everything works as expected if I run this program from a command prompt, as in I get the Hopper x: line printed plus the line numbers where the bits are set. If I run the program directly by clicking on the executable I get the hopper x: printing to stdout but no line numbers are printed, as if the program isn't finding anything.

My work around for this is to create a batch file that opens the executable and just run like that and it works. Just bugging me as to why

Thanks for the help

I tried adding various printf's to the code to see where it fails and as far as I can see it is not failing. It completes the loop and the file opens correctly as if I choose a non existent file I get the error message, getch() and return.

Comment: `if(strcmp(&compare, "1")` is incorrect. `compare` is a single character, not a 0 terminated string. You could use `if (compare == '1')` instead.

Comment: If you somehow can't format your code consistently as you type, then you could still at least pass it through a code formatter.  [This one](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier), for example.  I've done it for you this time.  I don't know how *you* manage to read or work on the version you posted, but good formatting makes that much easier for the rest of us.

Comment: `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and you need that to be able to reliably distinguish `EOF` from a valid `char`.